# can we return back to app without tapping it again?

Tags: iphone

HI 
can we open our app without tapping it again on its home icon.

I am making a call in a addressbook app and when call is made than it call the phone app than is it possible after calling we can call our app again without tapping on it after the call is ended.

Sample code will be more helpful.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer - no, once you leave your app, user has to return there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking, but if this is what you are shooting for:

a) Your app is running, and it causes a phone number to be dialed.
b) After the call is complete, your app is automatically re-launched.

Then no, this is not possible.